# Hide only part of text in TextView

Tags: android, text, view, hide

Good Day i want to hide some specified or certain part of text in textview!Important: Im not talking about hide the full textview with `TextView.setVisibility(View.Gone)` I'm not talking about transparent of TEXT in textview!im not talking about hiding full text in textview!So please help me to hide some text.
Example: lets say i have a textview with this text (10-Sporting Goods)
I want to hide the (10-) and show only Sporting Goods text.Any help will be appreciated!Thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: why don't you make the substring from the specified string and do textView.setText(substring); instead of hiding the textview partially?

Comment: change the text with tv.setText

Comment: ummm i have no idea about it so can you give me a responsive link where i could see what is that about?

Comment: You cant hide the sub-string , You can change the String.

Comment: Hmm here is my problem!Im fetching Json and i have to give response back with KEYS of json,so I'm fetching it with JSONOBJECT.KEYS() no other ways! but problem is that the keys giving reverse order and its crazy to show a user ui not normal order of things.So in that case I'm trying to hide that keys,on click get the current key and send to him,thats why I'm on this problem:(

Comment: WHAT PRICK DID PUT MINUSES!idiots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although even i would appreciate for your case to strongly go with DroidWorm/Gabriella approach , just for the information of all the other folks who may see this in future.

If you really wish to hide just a portion of your textview which has the entire string in itself, you should use a SpannableString , as below:-

```
        tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
        SpannableString customText = new SpannableString("10-Sporting Good");
        customText.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.1f), 0, 3, 0);
        tvHello.setText(customText);
```

This code will technically HIDE the **10-** from **10-Sporting Good** without using a substring.

Comment: Thank you only your choose did what i wanted exactly and helped me only!!!!THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get the whole text like

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

and then make substring of it like this:

```
String wantedSubstr = text.substring(4); //for example - everything from the 4th index to the end
```

then set this substring as text of your textView like this:

```
textView.setText(wantedSubstr);
```

Comment: Yea this is what I was aiming for. As long as there is a consistent prefix this would work.

Answer (score 1):

There is one the possible solution of it is that..First you have to find the index(position) of **"-"** and than split the string according to it therefore use below code

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
int position=text.indexOf('-');  
String wantedSubstr = text.substring(position+1);
textView.setText(wantedSubstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Will there always been "10_" in front of it? Or will there always be 3 characters before the text you want? Or will there always be a "-" or "_" before the text you want?

If so, you could just do a simple method which takes the substring and then updates the textview. If so I can help you write a simple method

Answer (score 0):

You `cannot hide part of textView`, **instead you can make a substring of the specific string and setText using it.**

Do it like:

```
String originalString = "10-Sporting Goods";
String subString = originalString.substring(3); 
textView.setText(asubstring);
```